# Are there any ways to speed up a complicated webform?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm sorry for probably stupid question.

But there is a problem we discussed with the client.

There is a complicated webform with about 180 components (including a lot of formula fields). (the tab node/*/webform)

Beside that, the webform contains about 30 conditionals.(the tab node/*/webform/conditionals)

Also the site owner can periodically change these formulas.

Some users can complain that the webform works a little slow.

Are there ways to speed up the webform without change it to a custom form + AJAX ?

Or, maybe, the simplest way is to upgrade hosting to more powerful one and with more powerful channel ?

Comment: You have to analyze the performance yourself; it depends on the specifics of the form.  If you think the formula fields are a problem, temporarily turn them off and see how much it speeds up.  If upgrading the hosting is an option, why not just try it out on a test server?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue in the Webform module for Drupal 8.  I think the best solution might be to literally split the 180 components across multiple webform instances. Right now, there is no 'out of the box' way to chain multiple forms together and this approach would require custom code.